# Defer all js file but slider revolution not run

Tags: wordpress

I have this code to defer all all js in my website using wordpress

```
if (!(is_admin() )) {
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;      
    return "$url' defer='defer";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );}
```

but revolution slider not woking with this code

Any help and advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good thing to defer all js of your WordPress, it will sure create issues, with your theme and plugins, as far as Revolution Slider is considered, try to follow these steps:

**Step 1:**

Go to `Revolution Slider` Global Settings

**Step 2:**

Under that find these 2 settings:

Insert JavaScript Into Footer: Select this to **ON**

Defer JavaScript Loading: Select this to **ON**

See the attached image:

[image]

**Step 3:**

Click **Update** button at the bottom. that's it .

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but in frontend like this
`/wp-content/plugins/revolution-slider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js" defer='defer' defer='defer'`


this code `defer='defer'` to double to display and revolution slider still not working